# Undefined method `pdf` with prawn-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to set up a basic PDF template with prawn-rails, and something's not quite right.

**Gemfile**:

```
gem 'prawn-rails'
```

which does grab the latest version (1.0.0).

**Controller**:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { render pdf: 'show.pdf.prawn' }
    # ...
  end
end
```

**HAML view**:

```
= link_to object_url(object, format: :pdf) do
  %button.btn.btn.default Print
```

**show.pdf.prawn**:

```
prawn_document do
  pdf.text "Some text"
end
```

**config/initializers/prawn-rails.rb**:

```
require 'prawn-rails'

PrawnRails.config do |config|
  config.page_layout = :portrait
  config.page_size = 'LETTER'
  config.skip_page_creation = true
end
```

This is all according to [the README](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails) of the prawn-rails repository.

But I get `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'pdf' for #<#<Class:0x005618ff5021e8>:0x005618ff97b968>)`.

Any thoughts? Should I just report this as an issue on the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
prawn_document do |pdf|
  pdf.text "Some text"
end
```

I'd send them a note and tell them to update their README.

Comment: I tried that. Gives `undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: @dfaulken Unfortunately, that sounds like a separate issue now, as opposed to the wrongly-documented API call before.

Comment: Okay. I opened an issue with them: https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails/issues/26.

Comment: If it turns out that it is unrelated, then I'm happy to accept your answer.

Comment: Good luck! I had a peek at your source and didn't spot anything obvious. I'd suggest posting the relevant stack trace for that new error if you have one, either to that ticket and/or to a new question on S/O.